deep learning performance stuck
Task
Multivariate time series forecast. I have one variable to forecast - and many explanatory variables. I want to train a model and then forecast the current period. This is for anomaly detection - comparing the actual value against the forecasted value.
I guess this is more like reconstruction than forecast.
I split the data into 120 windows, stepping through i step at at a time, and forecast the next value.
Problem
As a benchmark I throw together a linear regression and got the mse/mae from it.
I have then since trained numerous different deep learning models (GRU/LSTM's etc) and none of them beat the linear regression on mse or mae. This doesn't seem right, linear regression is not even meant for this type of problem and the linear regression does not preform particularly well.
What I want to know is - does this indicate that I am doing sometime wrong with the deep learning methods? Is there some fundamental mistake I have made or is this actually possible
An example forecast with the linear regression

this doesn't look amazing, surely it's not the best that is possible?? I expected an LSTM or something would at least match the linear regression?!
Details

data size - roughly 3 million rows, I can get more data if that is what is needed...
I have tried different batch sizes, different time steps- different architectures, LSTM's with different numbers of nodes, stacking up to 4 LSTMS, GRU, stacking multiple GRU, different optimizers (adam/RMSprop)
Linear regression gets an mse of 0.03, the best deep learning I have gets 0.09 ish
I have done a literature review and it all indicates that that deep learning is what is normally used in this domain

Any help much appreciated! Thanks
